# Is it possible to sync a Google Sheet with DB2/AS400

Tags: google-sheets, ibm-midrange

I would like to be able to synchronise a DB2/AS400 database with a Google sheet in order to use it with a Google Appsheet.

Is there a way to do this with Appscript for example?

Comment: Does the `DB2/AS400 database` offere some kind of API that allows you to fetch data with the [UrlFecthApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java and JDBC as decribed by this question and answer -- [How to connect Google Sheets to Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208721/how-to-connect-google-sheets-to-database).
Just use the JTOpen JDBC driver (https://sourceforge.net/projects/jt400/)  to connect to *Db2 for i*.